# Finding the outer boundary polygon of groups of long-lat coordinates in R

Tags: r, geometry, gis

I am analyzing a public database of government installations; row in this database represents a single building that may or may not be a part of a larger facility/installation. Overall, I have tens of thousands of buildings, most of which have long/lat coordinates. You can see the data [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/fy21-federal-real-property-profile).

I am trying to group them together with `dplyr` and other popular R libraries; as a part of a `group_by(installation_name) %>% summarise(...)` function, I am trying to create consolidated shapes for display in an ArcGIS/QGIS map. I need this script to do the following:

1. For installations with a single building, preserve the geometry as a point.
2. For installations with >= 2 buildings, create a polygon that connects the **outermost** points, without including inner points.

Say an installation had this set of points:

[scatter.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh0an.png)

I would want the generated polygon to look like this:

[polygon.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGjfp.png)

This is the closest I've come so far:

```
draw_poly <- function(lat_col, lon_col) {
  # Filter out NA values
  filtered_coords <- na.omit(cbind(lon_col, lat_col))

  if (nrow(filtered_coords) < 3) {
    # Not enough points to form a polygon, return the lat long as a coordinate point
    if (length(filtered_coords) == 0) {
      return(NA_character_)  # No coordinates available
    } else {
      return(st_as_text(st_point(filtered_coords[1, ])))
    }
  } else {
    # Create a closed polygon
    polygon <- st_polygon(list(rbind(filtered_coords, filtered_coords[1, ])))
    # Return the polygon as WKT (Well-Known Text)
    return(st_as_text(polygon))
  }
}
```

But the output ends up something like this:

[incorrect.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGMIl.png)

---

These are very rough ideations - some of these sites have 50+ buildings. I am aware of the `bbox` function from `sp`/`sf` but would like to get as precise with boundaries as possible. The ultimate goal here is an intersect with another complex shapefile, and we are afraid that forcing a square where an irregular x-gon would be more exact may lead to some false positives.

Comment: so basically you want to draw a hull around yout points? If so, take a look at the `sf::st_convex_hull()`-function

Comment: @Wimpel yes - is it possible to make hulls with straight lines as opposed to convex?

Comment: I suggest you try the st_convex_hull function, and take a look at the results (hint: the lines are straight)